# Silex, реально ли передать обьект Application в контроллер?

Tags: php, dependency-injection, silex

Привет.

Столкнулся с довольно таки странной проблеммой - я не могу в конструктор контроллера передать обьект класса \Silex\Application

А без него котроллер по сути мало чем полезен. В общем что именно я хочу получить - возможность из контроллера получить доступ к сервис контейнеру. (твиг, база данных и тп).

```
$app->get('/','AppComponents\Controllers\HelloController::index' );
```

Ну и сам код контролера

```
// HelloController.php

namespace AppComponents\Controllers;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;
use Silex;
use Silex\Application;

class HelloController{

    protected $app; 

    function __construct(Application $app) {
        $this->app = $app;
    }


    function index() {
        return  new Response("hello");
    }

}
```

Да, я знаю, что можно зарегестрировать котроллер как сервис, но хочется более просто решение.

Comment: А что мешает инжектить $app прямо в action?

`public function indexAction(Application $app)`

Answer (score 3):

Application передаётся параметром в экшен:

```
namespace AppComponents\Controllers;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;
use Silex;
use Silex\Application;

class HelloController
{

    function index(Application $app) {
        return  new Response("hello");
    }
}
```